# How to understand “take place" in the following sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning

How to understand the meaning of ***"place"*** in  "take place" and "take the place of" ?

Why does "take place" ***use "place" not "the place "*** and “take the place of”  use "the place" ? What's the difference between "place" and "the place" ?

Comment: You can't.  *Take place* is an idiom, which means it's **non-compositional**; you can't understand it as a combination of *take* and *place*.  (Although it's possible to meaningfully discuss the etymology of this idiom.)

Comment: @snailboat Which dictionary says it is an idiom?

Comment: "Take place" has a stand alone entry in dictionaries, for examples: [the free dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+place) or the [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_place). "Take the place of" hasn't.

Comment: It seems you didn't express your question very clearly, in the title you say it is about the word "place", but when we read the question itself you are asking about the use of the definite article "the" in one case and not in the other.

Comment: @user48070 If it were compositional, it wouldn't need its own dictionary entry, because you could understand it by looking up *take* and *place*.  But you can't understand it that way, so it does need [its own dictionary entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_place).

Answer (score 1):

When an event *takes place* it simply means that it *happened* or *occurred*. I consider this to be idiomatic because this has nothing to do with the definition of either *take* or *place*. I can't find a source that agrees, so I'd say that, at the very least, it's a phrase with only one possible meaning that's *frozen in time* so to speak. In other words, these words only have one application, which is unrelated to their traditional definitions.

With *takes the place* [of], *place* means stead, as in instead. It's another way of saying *substitutes for*, *replaces*, *assumes the role of*, or *takes the role of*. It's literal, with place meaning *position* rather than a location.

Answer (score 0):

WordReference says:

> *Take the place of* means replacing something, serving as proxy for or substitute for. The article *the* here means **the specific part (existing)** is getting replaced. 
>   
>   *Take place* means occur, come into being, arise, and result etc.

Let's see these examples:

> Auditions for *American Idol* to take place at .....(the event WILL take place, will occur)
>   
>   I could never take the place of your man (*the place* of *that man* only).